# Path for source files

Tags: application-development, python, quickly, glade

Where should I add source files for my program? I created a folder /data/src and put the files there. In my Python code I tried to point with os.getcwd() to it. This works for quickly run but if I install my application it gives me an IOEroor for home/username/myapp/data/src. How I can ajust the username?

Thanks

Comment: what sort of "source files"? do you mean python code?

Comment: No, just a text file which includes data. This data I need in the python code to create a dict and calculate something.

Comment: try $home instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you were able to get the `os.getcwd()` approach to work, it would probably break when you run the program installed. If you look in the `program_name_lib` directory, you'll see that quickly provides some convenience functions for you. The easiest way to do what you want is to put the text file in `data/media` and use the `get_media_file()` helper. Like so:

```python
from program_name_lib.helpers import get_media_file
text_file = get_media_file("my_file.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing details, it appears that it expects the directory `data/src` to be in you home directory, under your program name, and not in the root.  Did you really put it in `/data/src`?  Normally, I think it would go somewhere in your home directory, which you own and have full permissions.  You can, of course, change this and put it where you want, but it's usually best not to put things in the root directory.

Comment: But the media files are also in the data folder. How quickly finds them? Or are they copied after installation to the home directory? Sorry, up to now I programmed only for windows.

Comment: Sorry... I probably should just delete my post, as this is getting into too many details of your program and quickly that I don't know about.